# Require.js module not seeing Backbone Router.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

In this simple Require/Backbone app

https://github.com/thisishardcoded/require-prob

Why does app.js see Router but TestView.js not?

Here is the first line of app.js

```
define(['router'],function (Router) {
```

and here is the first line of TestView.js

```
define(['backbone','router'],function(Backbone,Router){
```

Check out the repo for full details, download, run and check console log if you feel so inclined

Thanks!
Jim

More: Ok, the answer is - because of the order in which it is loaded and even if that were altered I have a circular dependency don't I? TestView needs Router, Router needs TestView.

In which case the solution might be

```
var r=require('router);
r.navigate or whatever
```

but, that seems like a shame that Router is not directly accessible everywhere and, is the above method good practice anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely it happens because of circular dependency. To resolve it, you either pass router to view's constructor and remove router dependency from view's module, or use require('router') in your view.

1st option, router.js:

```
app_router.on('route:test', function () {
    var testView = new TestView({router: app_router});
    testView.render();
})
```

1st option, view.js:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone){

    var TestView=Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#test',
        initialize: function() {
            // get router from constructior options
            this.router = this.options.router
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html('<p>Foo!</p>');
            console.log("TestView.js does not find 'Router',", this.router);
        }
    });

    return TestView;

});
```

2nd option, view.js:

```
define(['backbone','router'], function(Backbone, router){

    // at this point router module is not loaded yet so router is undefined

    var TestView=Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#test',
        initialize: function() {
            // at this point router module is loaded and you may access it with require call
            this.router = require('router');
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html('<p>Foo!</p>');
            console.log("TestView.js does not find 'Router',", this.router);
        }
    });

    return TestView;

});
```

2nd option is also described here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

Comment: thanks, yes i've since realised i have a circular dependency - i guess i was thinking of router in terms of a singleton available across the entire app so ... is it considered good practice to pass the router around and also to use require() inline so to speak?

Comment: I tried to solve your particular problem of passing router in view. But now since you've asked about this being either good or bad, I think I would not choose this way, because it results in tightly coupled components. Instead I would make the router listen to view's events and call view's methods. So if the view needs router to do something, it will trigger the event. And if the router needs to use view, it will call its public method.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `baseUrl` property in your `main.js` file that contains RequireJS config.
In this way all paths to modules in your application will be relative to that `baseUrl`.

See:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl

Comment: Thank Eugene but I don't think it's to do with that. The router module is found but it's effectively 'empty'

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and inspected your code. Following could be the issues:

1. `require.js` only works with `AMDs`. Since backbone no longer supports `AMD`. You will need to use `AMD` enabled version of `Backbone`. You can get it [here](https://github.com/amdjs/backbone)
2. TestView is the dependency in you Router. So it loads before the Router is loaded.

You might want to improve the coding pattern. Here is my suggestion:

App.js

```
define([
```

'backbone',
  'router',
], function(Backbone, MainRouter){
    'use strict';

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){

        App.router = new MainRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
});

return AppView;
});
```

Router.js

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'view/TestView'
], function(Backbone, TestView){
    var Main = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'test': 'test'
        },

        test: function(){
            new TestView({
                // pass model or collection to the view
                // model: new TestModel // remember to require
            });
        }

    });

    return Main;
});
```

**EDIT**
Listening to events:

```
// in main.js
var window.Vent = {};

_.extend(window.Vent, Backbone.Events);

// now in any view you can trigger a event
$('something').on('click', function(){
    window.Vent.trigger('somethinghappened', this); 
    // this is reference to current object
});

// now in other view you can do
window.Vent.on('somethinghappened', this.run, this); 
// this in the end is the reference we passed when event was triggered

run: function(obj){
    //this function will run when the event is triggered
    // obj is the object who triggered the event
}
```

PS: why do you want to use router in view?? I have built quite a few backbone apps. Never needed to do so.

Comment: Hi, 1) didn't realise Backbone no longer AMD thanks 2) yes, since posting i've realised there's a circular dependency 3) i guess i was thinking of 'router' like a singleton available across the entire app, the reason i would want to use it in a view is because the close button on the dialog should launch another view 4) BUT .. i've since realised i'm kind of mis-understanding the use of router - I'm using an event dispatcher now instead

Comment: Great that you are doing your research. I have added a sample pattern you might want to follow. I have been using it for a while. Seems like you might want to use events then. You can trigger a event and listen for it in another view. I will add some sample code for that.

Comment: thank you! i'm a flash/actionscript refugee :) so far i'm loooooooving javascript - last time i touched it was a decade ago, OMG! it's grown up - sorry off-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use available `Backbone.history.navigate` to achieve your goal easier, because `Router.navigate` is a simple wrapper for it. Consider this [part of Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-149):

```
navigate: function(fragment, options) {
  Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
  return this;
},
```