# Backbone and Requirejs. How to access to my backbone router from everywhere

Tags: object, backbone.js, requirejs, global, router

I am working on my first project using requirejs. I have a router and a view and I would like to have access to my Router.navigate() method from the view when an item is clicked. I using CoffeeScript. how can I make router global?

router.coffee:

```
define [
'jquery'
'backbone'
'application/views/mainView'
'application/models/app'
],($,Backbone,MainView,App)->
class Router extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'organisation': 'organisationScreen'
    '*actions': 'organisationScreen'

  constructor:() ->
    super @routes

  initialize:()->

    Backbone.history.start() #pushState: true
    console.log " The Route Initialized"

  organisationScreen:()->
    $('.slides').fadeOut() 
    $('.confBlock').removeClass('onshow')
    $('.organisationsBlock').addClass('onshow')
```

view.coffee

```
define [
'jquery'
'backbone'
'application/views/conferenceView'
],($,Backbone,ConferenceView)->

class OrganisationView extends Backbone.View

  #el: '#appcontainer'

  tagName : 'li'
  className : 'organisation'

  events:
    'click .org-item' : 'choice'


  template : _.template($('#Organisation-template').html())

  initialize : ()->
   ...


  render: ()-> 
   ...

  choice:(ev)->
    # Call Router.navigate()
```

Comment: Why not just call `Backbone.history.navigate()`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth oooh, sorry, you forgot to post your question in the form of an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `Router::navigate` does is call `Backbone.history.navigate` so I would just use that. [Here is the source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1258)

```
choice: (ev)->
    Backbone.history.navigate(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply store your router along with other global variables you need in the Backbone object.

in your router init do the following:

```
    Backbone.application = {};
    Backbone.application.router = this;
```

then use it like this:

```
define(["backbone"], function (Backbone) {
     Backbone.application.router.myaction();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see three options for your problem:

1. Pass router in view constructor and use as local variable `@options.router`
2. Make circular dependency between two modules (check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314250/329226)
3. Trigger custom navigation event from view and listen to it from within the router

Comment: I already use solution 3 but I don't like it. Backbone.history.navigate() works fine. But Solution 2 helps me a lot for some other problems. Thanks a lot. :)